# How can I find $E_1$ and $E_1^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

> Suppose that: $E_1 \begin{bmatrix}12\\35\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}48\\35\end{bmatrix}$ Find $E_1$ and $E_1^{-1}$

I know how to find the inverse of a matrix, that's easy. It's just $E_1^{-1} = E_1 * I$

What I don't understand is how I can find $E_1$?

I know the equation in my book says $A\vec{x} = b$

Am I essentially finding $A$? If that is so, would I need to find the inverse of $x$?

So would I need to manipulate $Ax = b$ to $x^{-1}[Ax = b] = AI = x^{-1}b \implies A = x^{-1}b$?

Comment: For matrices $G$ and $H$, one can have $G^{-1}HG\neq H$, in particular when $G$ and $H$ do not commute, which is common for matrices, so your saying $x^{-1}Ax=AI=A$ is incorrect before even pointing out that matrices which are not square **never** have inverses.  There are infinitely many possible matrices $E_1$.

Comment: Also, $E_1^{-1}=E_1\cdot I$ is also false.  It will only be true in very specific situations which we call "self inverses."  An inverse of a square matrix, $A$, is the unique matrix $A^{-1}$ which satisfies $A\cdot A^{-1}=I$.  There are a number of methods of computing inverses.  Read any linear algebra textbook for more information on that.

Comment: What? Since when does $A*I \ne A^{-1}$? That isn't false.

Comment: @Shammy Yes, it's absolutely false in general. But just to check: By $*$, you do mean matrix multiplication, right? If so, then $AI = A^{-1}$ is equivalent to $A^2 = I$, which is almost always wrong. Looking at your post, you seem to have a **lot** of misconceptions about things: Vectors don't have inverses and matrix inverses aren't what you think they are.

Comment: What do you mean by $*$ then?  If you mean matrix multiplication, you have $A\cdot I = A$ in **every** case as $I$ is the notation for the identity.  In only very rare cases does $A=A^{-1}$.  Most times $A\neq A^{-1}$, for example the inverse of the $1\times 1$ matrix $A=[3]$ is $A^{-1}=[\frac{1}{3}]$

Comment: I think I am saying it wrong. I mean that $[A I ] = A^{-1}$ my apologies @JMoravitz

Comment: One can form an augmented matrix $[A\mid I]$ and row reduce.  $A$ is invertible if and only if the row reduced matrix is of the form $[I\mid B]$ where $B$ is some matrix and in that case $B$ happens to be $A^{-1}$.  This is essentially a rewording of the method of finding the inverse of a matrix via products of elementary matrices.

Comment: Correct @JMoravitz well glad I understand that now. Back to my original question tho in the OP, how exactly can I figure out what $E_1$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: this answer was written for the original form of the problem $E_1\begin{bmatrix}12\\35\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}48\\35\end{bmatrix}$.  The recent edit changed the numbers slightly, however the method is unchanged, just some numbers will be different in the end.  The final result is that the problem of finding $E_1$ is essentially one of a system of two equations and four unknowns, which is underdetermined.  If any solution exists, it will be infinitely many solutions.  Since the edit did not sufficiently change the problem, I will not update my answer to reflect the current numbers.*

---

Let $E_1=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$

The given conditions can be reworded as:

$\begin{cases} 12a+35b = 48\\ 12c+35d = 35\end{cases}$

Letting $a$ be anything, we can describe $b$ in terms of $a$.  Similarly, letting $c$ be anything, we can describe $d$ in terms of $c$.

Then, $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}a&(\frac{48-12a}{35})\\ c&(\frac{35-12c}{35})\end{bmatrix}$

In the case that the determinant of $E_1$ is nonzero, then it will have an inverse.

$E_1^{-1} = \frac{1}{a(\frac{35-12c}{35})-c(\frac{48-12a}{35})}\begin{bmatrix}(\frac{35-12c}{35})&-(\frac{48-12a}{35})\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$

Any choice of $a$ and any choice of $c$ such that the determinant is nonzero will form a matrix $E_1$ satisfying the desired conditions.  Hence, there are infinitely many solutions.

---

For example, with $a=c=1$ we have:  $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{36}{35}\\1&\frac{13}{35}\end{bmatrix}$

For another example, with $a=2$ and $c=-1$ we have $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}2&\frac{24}{35}\\-1&\frac{47}{35}\end{bmatrix}$

Notice that in *both* of those cases, we have $E_1\cdot \begin{bmatrix}12\\35\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}48\\35\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It's saying that $E_1$ is incorrect. How? I also had $55$ not $35$

Comment: @Shammy What is "*it*"?  If there is some online homework program which is asking you to find a single specific matrix $E$... I will have lost even more faith in the educational system.  There is no *one* answer as already mentioned, so if it wants a specific answer there must be missing information for the question.  As for you $55$ being changed with $35$, I already wrote the solution for if it were $35$ instead as you had originally posted.  I will not redo any calculations, you should be able to read and *understand* the answer and be able to do it yourself.

Comment: i re-edited the problem so that it is what it originally was. I also don;t know why I thought it was 55 when my original post was the correct version of the problem..Maybe it was just late at night and my brain was everywhere,Furthermore, the answer you've provided is still being marked as incorrect on my online homework program. I did:

$E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ so I have:

$12a + 35b = 48 \implies b = \frac{48-12a}{35}$

$12c +35d = 35 \implies d = \frac{35-12c}{35}$ where $a = c = 1$

So;we have: $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1&36/35\\1&23/35\end{bmatrix}$ which is wrong

Comment: My online homework is saying that the answer should instead be: $E_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 4&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ , which I have no clue how they are obtaining... The online homework is also saying that $E_1^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Perhaps (as also mentioned in the linked duplicate) that it is possible that $E_1$ should have been an **elementary matrix** and was missing from your post.  In that case, set $ b=0$ and $ c=0$ and solve for a and d in terms of b and c.

Comment: The post that I posted was exactly how the problem was given to me.

Comment: Wow @Jmoravitz that was it! They failed to mention that it was a elementary matrix, I'm reporting it to my professor now. Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: J if you can edit the question I can reward points to you, it seems it is locked right now though and I can't reward you the proper upvote.

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough information to uniquely determine an $E_1$. You can find one such $E_1$ that works by just setting the first column arbitrarily and solving for the second.

Also, $E^{-1}$ is the inverse of $E_1$. It is not true that $E^{-1} = (E_1)(I) = E_1$.

Comment: No offense, but this is not really an answer. If it is, it really is lacking information because I am still unsure of how to solve for $E_1$.. Are you implying I just make up numbers for the entries of $E_1$?

Comment: It *is* an answer, @Shammy, just without doing the computations. In general, knowing the action of a matrix on a single vector is not enough to determine the matrix. After all, if $E$ is a solution, so is $E + N$ where $N$ is any matrix whose null space contains $[12, 35]^T$.

Comment: It may be *an* answer, but that doesn't necessarily  make it a *good* answer. That is all I was alluding to.

Comment: @Shammy It *is* a good answer.

Comment: @egreg That is *your* opinion, friend. ;)